# Pandas: How to merge two data frames and fill NaN values using values from the second data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fillna

I have a pandas dataframe (df1) that looks like this:

```
No     car          pl.       Value      Expected      
1      Toyota       HK        0.1        0.12      
1      Toyota       NY        0.2        NaN     
2      Saab         LOS       0.3        NaN      
2      Saab         UK        0.4        0.6       
2      Saab         HK        0.5        0.51     
3      Audi         NYU       0.6        NaN      
3      Audi         LOS       0.7        NaN      
4      VW           UK        0.8        NaN   
5      Audi         HK        0.9        NaN
```

And I have another dataframe (df2) that looks like this:

```
No        pl.             Expected              
2         LOS              0.35      
3         NYU              0.62   
3         LOS              0.76    
5         HK               0.91
```

I would like my final dataframe to look like this:

```
No     car          pl.       Value      Expected      
1      Toyota       HK        0.1        0.12      
1      Toyota       NY        0.2        NaN     
2      Saab         LOS       0.3        0.35      
2      Saab         UK        0.4        0.6       
2      Saab         HK        0.5        0.51     
3      Audi         NYU       0.6        0.62      
3      Audi         LOS       0.7        0.76      
4      VW           UK        0.8        NaN   
5      Audi         HK        0.9        0.91
```

I tried this:

```
df = df1.fillna(df1.merge(df2, on=['No','pl.']))
```

But df1 remains unchanged in the output

The questions that I have seen here have been of dataframes with the same shape. Is there a way to do this when the shapes are different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join with `suffixes` parameter and then replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and drop column `Expected_`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['No','pl.'], how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
df['Expected'] = df.pop('Expected_').fillna(df['Expected'])
print (df)
   No     car  pl.  Value  Expected
0   1  Toyota   HK    0.1      0.12
1   1  Toyota   NY    0.2       NaN
2   2    Saab  LOS    0.3      0.35
3   2    Saab   UK    0.4      0.60
4   2    Saab   HK    0.5      0.51
5   3    Audi  NYU    0.6      0.62
6   3    Audi  LOS    0.7      0.76
7   4      VW   UK    0.8       NaN
8   5    Audi   HK    0.9      0.91
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we have two key columns where we want to match on and update our `df1` dataframe, we can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), since `fillna` aligns in the indices:

```
keys = ['No', 'pl.']
df1 = df1.set_index(keys).fillna(df2.set_index(keys)).reset_index()

   No  pl.     car  Value  Expected
0   1   HK  Toyota    0.1      0.12
1   1   NY  Toyota    0.2       NaN
2   2  LOS    Saab    0.3      0.35
3   2   UK    Saab    0.4      0.60
4   2   HK    Saab    0.5      0.51
5   3  NYU    Audi    0.6      0.62
6   3  LOS    Audi    0.7      0.76
7   4   UK      VW    0.8       NaN
8   5   HK    Audi    0.9      0.91
```

---

Or we can use the dedicated method [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) for this:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(keys)
df1['Expected'].update(df2.set_index(keys)['Expected'])
df1 = df1.reset_index()

   No  pl.     car  Value  Expected
0   1   HK  Toyota    0.1      0.12
1   1   NY  Toyota    0.2       NaN
2   2  LOS    Saab    0.3      0.35
3   2   UK    Saab    0.4      0.60
4   2   HK    Saab    0.5      0.51
5   3  NYU    Audi    0.6      0.62
6   3  LOS    Audi    0.7      0.76
7   4   UK      VW    0.8       NaN
8   5   HK    Audi    0.9      0.91
```

Comment: I get key error with both methods. I guess because there are a few rows with values in both cols. Any suggestions how to handle this situation?